# Laravel migration UP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

With the command `php artisan migrate:make webLinks --table webLinks`
 I can create a migration file, the generated output below.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class WebLinks extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('webLinks', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('weblink');
        $table->string('verifyCode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('webLinks', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
    });
}
```

}

Now I cannot use Up for create table with fields:
command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(81) "select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?"
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "ads"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "migrations"
  }
  [2]=>
  float(0.44)
  [3]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this little helper from Jeffrey Way??
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

This might be helpful.